# How to extract data from CSV file which exists in Sharepoint and load them directly into SQL Server Management Studio database

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint, ssis, ssms

I want to extract data from CSV file which exists in Sharepoint and load them directly into SQL Server Management Studio database.
Do you have any idea how to do it?
Can I use SSIS for that? Or SQL ?
Please let me know.
Thanks in advance for doing this.

Comment: This is a pretty vague cry for help. What part(s) of this process are struggling with?

Comment: I tried to use SSIS but I couldn't load data from sharepoint csv file to database. Do you have any idea how to do it?

Comment: @SeanLange do you any way to do that? Thanks in advance for answering my question.