# Export data from Sharepoint file and load it automatically into SSMS database

Tags: sql, sql-server, url, sharepoint, ssis

I want to export data from CSV file which exists in Sharepoint and load them directly into SQL Server Management Studio database.
Do you have any idea how to do it?
Can I use SSIS for that? Or SQL ?
Please let me know.
Thanks in advance for doing this.

Comment: Please try some basic searching (e.g., google or bing or ... "export from sharepoint to sql server") as a first step to solving any problem. Your question is not suited to this site which is intended to answer specific technical questions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to extract data from CSV file which exists in Sharepoint and load them directly into SQL Server Management Studio database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72604760/how-to-extract-data-from-csv-file-which-exists-in-sharepoint-and-load-them-direc)